# Add texture for reflectivity of MeshPhysicalMaterial

Tags: three.js

i'm looking for a way to use a MeshPhysicalMaterial in Three.js but i'd like to use a texture as reflectivity parameter (like a reflectivityMap...). Is there a simple way to do that in js ?? The idea is to be able to manage the quantity of the reflection by a texture on a surface (cause the roughness seems to be only for the smoothness of the reflection but no the quantity...).
thks a lot !

Comment: If by simple way you mean a built-in `reflectivityMap` material parameter, then no. You can, however, utilize `onBeforeComiple` to dynamically include a `reflectivityMap` uniform and modify the fragment shader to use that instead of the built-in `reflectivity` parameter.

Comment: Thks a lot ScieCode. Unfortunatly, i don't have enough the skills to do that cause i don't know hox to proceed. Do you know an example (as jsfiddle) to understand how to do that ? Thanks again for your respone !

Comment: Not exactly a ReflectivityMap, but it serves a similar purpose: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/sciecode/pen/eYYJGgp)

Comment: Thks ScieCode ! Your example is very useful ! I've tried to integrate it to my project and it's work ! The only problem is that i'm not able to change the texture use as reflectivityMap dynamically (with a material.needsupdate for example) ;( An idea ??? thks again for your collaboration !

Comment: You can, there's no need for a `material.needsUpdate`. Simply do it like so: `material.uniforms.reflectivityMap.value = newTexture` and it will update automatically. Glad it helped you out.

Comment: I'm sorry but i tried it and obtained a n error : cannot read property 'reflectivityMap' of undefined ;(

Comment: I'm happy to tell you i found the solution. I added `materialShader = shader;` in the `onBeforeCompile` and after i change the texture with `materialShader.uniforms.reflectivityMap.value = newtexture`. Thanks again for your help !!!!!!

Comment: Oh yeah, that is actually the correct way of handling this. My previous suggestion was indeed incorrect.